# SVN Merge Question

Tags: svn

Suppose that I have two massive folders in SVN: test and prod. I'm trying to use the following svn command to merge the content from test into prod:

`svn merge ./prod@HEAD ./test@HEAD ./prod`

However, my SVN repository is huge and this process takes an enormous amount of time. Is there any way that I can make a simpler merge statement which will be more processor friendly? Perhaps a server-URL based merge?

Any insight is appreciated....

Answer (score 2):

Merge operation is nothing but calculating diff and applying it on the client. Important: merge doesn't change repository - it just changes local copy. So there is no way to do it on the server-side only.

Answer (score -4):

If your intent is to make the folder "prod" look just like "test", why not just delete the "prod" folder on the server, then copy the "test" folder to where "prod" used to be?  No merge necessary.

Comment: Because that would generally defeat the purpose of actually merging folders. That would instead be called "deleting and renaming"